# Extending Cash.State in CORDA

Tags: kotlin, corda

We are using the cash state for `FungibleAsstes` as we have a similar scenario but we need some extended functionality with the existing ones.

We need to create a transaction with a single move command and multiple states. Each states will contain a fraction of total amount from multiple issuers(the amount for each issuers will be provided by us) for that node.

Is there a way to extend the `Cash.States` class for this feature.

```
issuerConstraint.forEach {
                pair = try {
                    Cash.generateSpend(serviceHub,
                            builder,
                            distributedAmount,
                            recipient,
                            setOf(it))

                } catch (e: InsufficientBalanceException) {
                    throw CashException("Insufficient cash for spend: ${e.message}", e)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you need to change the behaviour of `Cash.State` itself, or of the `Cash` contract? What happens when you try and implement the scenario above with the existing `Cash.State`? Does contract verification fail?

Comment: yes..i call 'Cash.generateSpend' in a loop and because of that it creates multiple Move commands and fails..i have updated the question with some code..

Comment: Ah.. I think the Cash Move verification should be changed to allow multiple move commands... What you can do in the interim is union together all the public keys from the multiple commands into one single command.

Comment: @RogerWillis how do i do that..should i create a new transactionbuilder?..can you please provide some code snippet..

Answer (score 0):

Try using the more generic `OnLedgerAsset.generateSpend` method instead. It works for any `FungibleAsset`, including `Cash`.

`OnLedgerAsset.generateSpend` allows you to specify how the move command is generated.